# Prove that all integers $n$ with $n \ge 12 $ is in the set.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

$T = \{3k+7m: k,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $ k \ge 0, m\ge 0\}$

I assume I would do this by induction, so I want to show $3k+7m=n$ for $n\ge 12$.

for the base case $n=12$.

$3k + 7m = 12$ is true for when $k=6 $ and $m=0$, so base case is ok.

If we assume $3k + 7m = r$, for $r \ge 12, k \ge 0, m\ge 0$ is true, then we now show $3k + 7m = r+1$ is true. How would I go about this? Or have I thought about this method incorrectly?

Comment: Infact, a general statement is as follows: If positive integers $ a,b $ are relatively prime, then the largest positive integer which is inexpressible in the form $ ax+by, x,y \ge 0 $ is $ ab-a-b $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T = \{3k+7m: k,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $ k \ge 0, m\ge 0\}$

$3k + 7m = 12$ is true for when $k=4 $ and $m=0$, so base case is ok.
Please note that

Let $$T_n=3k_n + 7m_n$$
$$T_{n+1} = T_n+1 = 3(k_n-2)+7(m_n+1)$$
$$T_{n+2} = T_n+2 = 3(k_n-4)+7(m_n+2)$$
$$T_{n+3} = T_n+3 = 3(k_n-6)+7(m_n+3) = 3(k_n+1)+7m_n$$

For $T_n$ to be in the set, $k_n,m_n \ge 0$ for all $n$
As can be seen from the above generator functions, the least value $k_n$ can be allowed to take is $4$ (to allow $k_n-4 \ge 0$), which is true in the base case $T_1=12$.

Hence, we have $T_1$ in the set, and we have $T_{n+1}$ in the set if $T_n$ is in the set. This should be sufficient for the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Induction will work, but it has to be modified somewhat. I would recommend establishing three base cases: $n=12,13,14$. Then show for $r \geq 12$, if $r=3k+7m$ for some $k,m$, then $r+3=3k'+7m'$ for some $k',m'$. This will suffice, because the base cases along with the induction step imply that $15,16,17$ can be written in this form, and thus $18,19,20$, and $21,22,23$, etc.